# Flatpak uninstall fails: assertion failed: (commit != NULL)

Tags: flatpak

I installed [PeaZip](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.peazip.PeaZip) using Flatpak:

```bsh
$ flatpak install flathub io.github.peazip.PeaZip
Looking for matches…
Remote ‘flathub’ found in multiple installations:

   1) system
   2) user

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]: 1
Skipping: io.github.peazip.PeaZip/x86_64/stable is already installed
```

Now, I can't uninstall it:

```bsh
$ flatpak uninstall flathub io.github.peazip.PeaZip
Warning: flathub is not installed
**
flatpak:ERROR:common/flatpak-transaction.c:2971:mark_op_resolved: assertion failed: (commit != NULL)
Bail out! flatpak:ERROR:common/flatpak-transaction.c:2971:mark_op_resolved: assertion failed: (commit != NULL)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

I'm not familiar with Flatpak. Can anyone help?

I'm running Flatpak 1.10.2 on Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce you issue while using Flatpak 1.10.2 from official Ubuntu 21.10 repository.

To remove this problematic PeaZip package you need to get newer FlatPak from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=focal) using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -n ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo sed -i "s/impish/focal/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-impish.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

flatpak uninstall io.github.peazip.PeaZip
```

Note: uninstall command [does not require](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/flatpak-install.1.html) *flathub* (remote) argument.

Comment: No better luck I'm afraid:

```~$ flatpak uninstall io.github.peazip.PeaZip
**
flatpak:ERROR:common/flatpak-transaction.c:2971:mark_op_resolved: assertion failed: (commit != NULL)
Bail out! flatpak:ERROR:common/flatpak-transaction.c:2971:mark_op_resolved: assertion failed: (commit != NULL)
Abandon (core dumped)```

Comment: Sounds really strange. I would recommend running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flatpak` . Then retry.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I raised the issue on the package [GitHub repo](https://github.com/flathub/io.github.peazip.PeaZip).

Comment: See updated answer above. There is something wrong between Flatpak from official repository and PeaZip flatpak package. The problem is fixable by using newer Flatpak from PPA.